# Is my logic on a bitshifting question right?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

im just about done with an assignment and on the last question I have attempted to do it but I dont know if I used the bitshifting correctly.

For the question, I had to extract the right byte of an integer, then get the first 3 bits, next 3 bits, and last 2 bits of that right byte and assign it to unsigned integer variables.

What I have tried so far is:

```
   int rightmost = (y>>24)&0xFF // to get rightmost byte
   int first = (rightmost <<< 1)&0xFF // to get first 3 bits of that byte
   int second = (rightmost >>> 3)&0xFF // to get next 3 bits
   int third = (rightmost >>> 6)&0xFF // to get last 2 bits
```

Id just like to know if I am going in the right direction

Comment: The meaning of "left" and "right" depend on your CPU. On an Intel-family CPU, the "rightmost" byte is `x && 0xff`.

Comment: @Pointy Im just having to get the rightmost byte of an integer varible y, theres nothing assigned to it right now because its just a "what if" kinda question. Im on an AMD cpu anyway

Comment: @Pointy anything else you can let me know about my logic? I dont know if I got the first 3 bits right

Comment: AMD and Intel CPUs are the same. If you have a 32-bit number whose value is `1`, that `1` bit will be in the least-significant byte, and in JavaScript you'd get that with a simple `& 0xFF`. No need to shift.

Comment: And actually now that I think about it my original comment is probably wrong; the implementation of `>>` is such that it implements the *logical* bit ordering, not the in-memory bit/byte ordering.

Comment: @Pointy Ahhh ok I see. How about the 3 variables I made to get first second and third bits of that byte, was I right?

Comment: See my answer. I'm checking it over again to make sure I haven't goofed again ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do this:

```
var firstByte = y & 0xff;
```

That's the least-significant byte. If the value in `y` is `12`, all the bits will be in that byte.

Then, to isolate the parts of that byte, you have to use `&` to chop off all the bits you *don't* want, and then `>>` to get the bits into the least-significant positions. The order in which you do that doesn't matter, though it does dictate what you put on the other side of `&`:

```
var first3 = firstByte & 0x07; // no need to shift
var second3 = (firstByte >> 3) & 0x07; // shift by 3 and then mask off the rest
var last2 = (firstByte >> 6) & 0x03; // shift by 6 and mask
```

In binary, `0x07` looks like `00000111`. Thus using `&` with that isolates the least-significant 3 bits in a number.

Test below.

JavaScript is kind-of weird because in between all those operations the language maintains the numbers as 64-bit floating-point values. For integer values however that doesn't really matter, and indeed an optimized runtime may not actually keep the floating point representations around, if it's really smart about things.

```js
    var y = 2359; // binary: 100100110111

    var firstByte = y & 0xff;
    console.log("firstByte: " + firstByte);

    var first3 = firstByte & 0x07;
    console.log("should be 7: " + first3); // should be 7

    var second3 = (firstByte >> 3) & 0x07;
    console.log("should be 6: " + second3); // should be 6

    var last2 = (firstByte >> 6) & 0x03;
    console.log("should be 0: " + last2); // should be 0
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew my logic was somewhat correct on the second and third but I wasnt sure about the masking part on them, I really appreciate the insight!